# How can I make my HTML elements be equal column width when the window is shrunk in CSS liquid design?

Tags: html, css, background, element, liquid-layout

I have my code in this fiddle:  [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rafxfqgy/)

1. I have two HTML element columns:

   ```
   <aside>This is the aside</aside>

   <section>This is the section</section>
   ```

The `<aside>` is at 33% width of the `<div id="wrapper">` while the `<section>` is at 66% (The `<div id="wrapper">` itself is at 100% of the opened internet window browser).

When I shrink the window, I want the columns to stack right on top of each other in an equal column width (so that would require changing each of the width from either the 33% (or 66%) to 100% when the window is shrunk).

But I'm having trouble doing this.

2. is it possible to have another separate `<div id="background1"`> and <`div id="background2"`> that would overlap behind the `<aside>` and `<section>` elements and change width columns along with them as a background?

How may I do this?

Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a media query

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/rafxfqgy/4/)

```
@media screen and (max-width: 430px) {
  aside, section {
    width: auto;
    float: none;
  }
  footer {
    padding: 10px 10px;
  }     
}
```

Comment: Nice!  But something happens to my Footer when the window is shrunk... it it's width goes past the wrapper.  Would an overflow: hidden fix that?

Comment: @5120bee That is caused by the huge padding you use `padding: 10px 200px;` ... 200px on each side gives a total width of 400px ... you can reduce that with the same media query ... updated my answer

Comment: Ah I see it now.  Thanks, I'll just have to put my <p> element in the Footer into another <div> within it.

Answer (score 2):

If you write media query in mobile-friendly approach then you can achieve the result.

define width into media query:

```css
@media (min-width: 400px) {
  aside {
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
  }
  section {
    width: 66%;
    float: right;
  }
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rafxfqgy/5/)